# Partial specialization of typedef

Tags: c++, using, partial-specialization

I want to have a type which is either a typedef or a class. Thus, something like this

```
template< typename T > class A { };
template< typename T > using X< T, true > = T;
template< typename T > using X< T, false > = A< T >;
```

Obviously, this does not compile.

To overcome this problem I "invented" the following construct, which seems quite complicated in my eyes:

```cpp
template< typename T > class A { }; 

template< typename T, bool E > struct make_X;

template< typename T >
struct make_X< T, true > {
    T make();
};

template< typename T >
struct make_X< T, false > {
    A< T > make();
};

template< typename T, bool E > using X = decltype( make_X<T,E>::make() );
```

Is there an easier way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, one would do this:

```
template< typename T, bool E > using X = std::conditional_t<E, T, A<T>>;
```

The only issue here would be if you wanted to use the type `X<T, true>` in a situation where simply mentioning `A<T>` would be ill-formed. In that case `X<T, true>` will be ill-formed even though the result is not `A<T>` anyway. If this is a possible situation, then something more complicated, like what you wrote, could be appropriate in order to make sure that `A<T>` is never even mentioned in the first place. However, in general, this would be done using type aliases in the partial specializations (*e.g.* `using type = T;`) and not through functions, in case `T` or `A<T>` is some kind of type that is not allowed as a function return type.